# put $.getJSON(url, function(data) in a loop but yield wrong result

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous

I run several calls to the Instagram API by using a loop but it yields weird result that I couldn't understand.

```
for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){

    document.write('search: ' + i + 'round');
    document.write(tags[i] + ' ');
    document.write('<hr />');
    var url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'+ tags[i] +'/media/recent?&client_id=5a7b13571ced47418dd539e6fc97a67f&count='+count+'&callback=?';

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        console.log(data.data.length);

        if(data.data.length === 0){
            //$('ul.images').append('<li>No results</li>');

        } else {

            $.each(data.data, function(index, value){
            //console.log(value);
                var imgUrl = value.images.low_resolution.url,
                imgUser = value.user.username,
                imgLink = value.link;
                it.push(imgLink);

                document.write(value.link + '<br />');
                //$('ul.images').append('<li><a href="'+imgLink+'" target="_blank"><img src="'+imgUrl+'"/></a></li>');
            });
        }
        document.write('---------------------'  + '<br />');
    });
}
```

When I search three tags, cat, dog, pig, the result is:

```
search: 0roundcat
search: 1rounddog
search: 2roundpig

5 instagram image links
---------------------

5 instagram image links
---------------------

5 instagram image links
---------------------
```

So it seems the it first loop the three `document.write()` statement and then getting into `$.getJSON()` statement.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the problem? Your code outputs what one would expect.

Answer (score 1):

*If* your question is why the "i + round + tag" output comes before the output with the links, that is because `getJSON()` is **asynchronous**, i.e. it starts a request and **returns immediately**.
Then, after the `for` loop is finished, the execution has returned to the event loop and the results of the asynchronous requests have arrived, they are printed in the order that they arrived.

There are several ways to get around this, one would be something like this:

```
var tags = ['cat','dog','pig'];
function start_next_request() {
  var tag = tags.shift();
  var url = ...
  $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    ...
    start_next_request();
  }
}
start_next_request();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, AndreKR！It's really helpful, I am wondering if there's anyway, we could run getJSON several time and store the result each time in an array? I really can not think up another way without loop. THX

Comment: I tried this one, still no luck. What I really want to do is using an array, and push value within getJSON in them and still can access them outside getJSON. The method I use above, still have the array empty. Thanks anway, Any more suggestions?

Comment: In your example you don't have an array but `document.write()`. If you want to use an array, which is good, the simplest way is probably to make it global.